# How do you set the document title using Purescript?

Tags: purescript, purescript-pux

After searching for some time I found in Pursuit the module `DOM.HTML.History` which has the data type `DocumentTitle`. This type could probably be used together with the function

```
replaceState ::
  ∀ e. Foreign -> DocumentTitle -> URL -> History -> Eff (history :: HISTORY | e) Unit
```

To change the `document.title` property of the page, however, I can't find examples showing how to call this function (e.g., where do I get the external `Foreign` data type?). Also, I'm not even sure if this function would do what I expect it to do...

Comment: `replaceState` seems related to the HTML5 History API. Probably not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In the unfortunate case that the Purescript team didn't include in their core API a way to change the document title, it's still possible to do so by making use of purescript's handy FFI mechanism.

Add these two files into your project:

**Document.js**

```
exports.setDocumentTitle =
  function (title)
  {
    return function ()
    {
      window.document.title = title;
    };
  };
```

**Document.purs**

```
module Document
where

import Control.Monad.Eff (kind Effect, Eff)
import Data.Unit (Unit)

foreign import data DOCUMENT :: Effect

foreign import setDocumentTitle ::
  ∀ fx . String -> Eff (document :: DOCUMENT | fx) Unit
```

Now you can call `setDocumentTitle` as you would call Console's `log` function, except the effect would be `DOCUMENT` instead of `CONSOLE`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

kazouas answer would look like this (in PS 0.12)

```
import Effect (Effect)
import Data.Unit (Unit)

foreign import setDocumentTitle :: String -> Effect Unit
```

Javascript remains the same.